# Remove Sidebar from Wordpress

Tags: sidebar

I successfully removed or hide all sidebar text on my website.

Unfortunately the sidebar still remains (it's just blank, doesn't show anything).

This makes my page not appear wide enough.

How can i completely remove the sidebar?

I use Ribbon Lite theme.

Answer (score 3):

If Ribbon Lite doesn't have within its configuration settings an option to completely hide the sidebar (e.g. under "Appearance > Customize"), you're likely going to have to modify some of the theme files themselves (PHP and likely CSS as well).

Removing the WordPress sidebar is covered in detail in numerous places all over the internet; it's going to be a similar process regardless of the theme you're using:

> For example, in a typical WordPress theme you may need to edit
>   index.php, page.php, single.php, archive.php, home.php and so on.
>
> Open a template file to edit it and then locate the line that looks
>   like this:
>
> ```
> <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
> ```
>
> Delete the line that represents the sidebar that you don’t want to
>   display.
>
> Now, save and upload the file back to your website. Repeat the process
>   for all template files responsible for displaying different pages on
>   your website.

Taken from: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-remove-the-sidebar-in-wordpress/

Ideally you'll do this in a child theme, that way your changes don't get overwritten if the Ribbon Lite theme ever receives an update.